# inappropriate error response issue with silent sign-in identity server 4

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, error-handling, identityserver4, openid-connect

I'm trying to implement silent login in oidc-client to use with Angular 9 and want the user to be auto logged in after registration within an ASP.NET Core app after email verification.

I've got all the bits working except the very last step, i.e. the getting actual error in response in order to show appropriate message for client according to possible error. There are two possible errors that need to be handled :

1) texted one time code is not correct;

2) one time code is expired.

That's why I have to pass exact code description on server side and handle it on client side afterwards.

client side code:

```
export function getClientSettings(identityBaseUrl: string): UserManagerSettings {
  const baseUrl = window.location.origin;

  return {
    authority: identityBaseUrl,
    client_id: 'test.admin.spa',
    redirect_uri: `${baseUrl}/auth-callback`,
    post_logout_redirect_uri: baseUrl,
    response_type: 'id_token token',
    scope: 'openid profile test.admin.api',
    filterProtocolClaims: true,
    loadUserInfo: true,
    userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage }),
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri: `${baseUrl}/silent-refresh.html`,
  };
}
```

This is the way how I'm overriding ProcessInteractionAsync method within a custom AuthorizeInteractionResponseGenerator:

```
        public override async Task<InteractionResponse> ProcessInteractionAsync(ValidatedAuthorizeRequest request, ConsentResponse consent = null)
        {
            var processOtcRequest = !_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

            var acrValues = request.GetAcrValues().ToList();
            if (acrValues.Any() == false)
            {
                processOtcRequest = false;
            }

            var userEmailAcr = acrValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("user_email"));
            var oneTimeCodeAcr = acrValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartsWith("one_time_code"));

            if (userEmailAcr != null && oneTimeCodeAcr != null && processOtcRequest)
            {
                var userEmail = userEmailAcr.Split(':').Last();
                var oneTimeCode = oneTimeCodeAcr.Split(':').Last();
                var currDate = DateTime.UtcNow;

                var user = await _users.GetUserByEmailAsync(userEmail);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // 1) texted one time code is not correct
                    if (user.OneTimeCode != oneTimeCode)
                    {
                        return GetErrorResponse("invalid_code");
                    }

                    // 2) one time code is expired
                    if (user.OneTimeCodeExpiredAt < currDate)
                    {
                        return GetErrorResponse("expired_code");
                    }

                    user.EmailConfirmed = true;
                    user.OneTimeCode = null;
                    user.OneTimeCodeExpiredAt = null;
                    user.SecurityStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper();
                    user.ConcurrencyStamp = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper();
                    user.NormalizedEmail = user.Email.ToUpper();
                    user.NormalizedUserName = user.UserName.ToUpper();

                    if (request != null)
                    {
                        request.Subject = new ClaimsPrincipal({{building my principal}});
                    }

                    await _users.UpdateAsync(user);
                    await _users.CommitAsync();

                    var props = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(2),
                        AllowRefresh = true,
                        RedirectUri = request.RedirectUri
                    };

                    await _loginService.SignInAsync(user, props);

                    return new InteractionResponse
                    {
                        IsLogin = false,
                        IsConsent = false
                    };
                }

            }

            return await base.ProcessInteractionAsync(request, consent);
        }

        private InteractionResponse GetErrorResponse(string errorCode)
        {
            return new InteractionResponse
            {
                Error = errorCode
            };
        }
```

So, it looks quite logical but when I texted one time code incorrect code and tried to handle error on client side:

```
  sendRequest(postModel: RegisterCompanyConfirbut mationViewModel) {
    this.authService.startSilentAuthentication(this.userEmail, this.form.value.oneTimeCode).then(
      (result) => {
        this.router.navigate(['', 'company-details']);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

I observed such weird thing in error section:

[window timeout exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xmuzh.png)

From the other hand, when I looked the network section and clicked on this record

[error in network section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9XxD.png)

I saw that my error code has been sent nevertheless:

[expected error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm4lY.png)

I see that simple return error like this

```
            return new InteractionResponse
            {
                Error = errorCode
            };
```

doesn't bring me error that I expected (it brought me only "Frame window timed out" instead).

The purpose is to retrieve the information about error with one time code  in the section on client side:

```
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

Perhaps anyone bumped into such kind of problem? Any pointers would be gratefully received - this simple problem just boggles my mind.. Thanks in advance!